# How to use JSX in a web worker with Vite?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using the [@remote-ui/react](https://github.com/Shopify/remote-ui/tree/main/packages/react) library to render my React code in a web worker. I'm using Vite for my project, but whenever I try to use JSX in my worker script, I see the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
```

I've created a minimal reproduction [here](https://github.com/glocore/vite-remote-ui-example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disabling React Fast Refresh seems to do the trick:

```
// vite config
{
  plugins: [react({ fastRefresh: false })],
  worker: {
    plugins: [react()],
  },
}
```

Comment: but that slows down the live reload just refreshes the page for every change, don't know why I got this bug all of a sudden

Comment: `fastRefresh` is something that doesn't seem to exist anymore according to Intellisense, and even if I specify it and restart the server, the error keeps coming up.

Comment: @JoséRamírez `fastRefresh` was removed in latest Vite. and the problem with refresh is an ongoing issue discussed here https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5396

Answer (score 19):

If by chance, anyone encountered the same error using **Laravel Vite**, one might forget to add `@viteReactRefresh` before the `@vite` blade directive as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#react).

Comment: Yesssssssssssssssss!